# JavaScript と PHP だけで JSONP の挙動を確認したいのですが…

Tags: javascript

jQueryを使用せず、JavaScriptとPHPだけでJSONPの挙動を確認したいのですが…

▼index.html

```
function check(arg) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript"; 
  script.src = 'hoge.php?arg='+arg;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
function callback(last) {
  console.log(last)
}
```

▼hoge.php

```
$arg = ($_GET['arg']);
print "callback($arg);";
```

このとき、引数を数字にすると問題ないのですが、文字列へ変更するとエラーになります
・check(9); … 〇
・check('沖縄'); … ×

・どう修正すればよいでしょうか？
・JSONPではなく、エスケープの問題？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPで `"なんとか $hoge かんとか"` といった感じで変数の値を埋め込む場合、自動的に引用符で囲まれる、といったことはありません。もし `callback('沖縄')` という形に展開したいのであれば、自分で引用符で囲む必要があります。

が、JSONPということですし `json_encode()` を使ってはいかがでしょう。

```
$arg = json_encode($_GET['arg']);
print "callback($arg)";
```

なお `$_GET` に含まれる値は全て文字列になっているので、もし数値を数値としてJSONにエンコード、コールバック関数に渡したいのであれば、 [`is_numeric()` 等で判別して数値に変換する](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.is-numeric.php#107326)といった処理が必要になります。

Comment: 回答提示いただいた「json_encode()を使用する方法」でも、「自分で引用符で囲む方法」でも確認できました。参考までにJSONPの考え方について教えてください。引用符を自分で囲む方法だとJSONを全く使用しなくても済むのですが、この場合もJSONPになるのでしょうか？ Wikiを見ると「JSONを組み合わせて実現される」と書いてありますが、別に使用しなくても良い？ データを受け渡しする際JSON使用すると便利だからJSONがよく使用されるだけ、ってことでしょうか？

Comment: 便利だからと言うか、JSONをクロスドメインで利用するテクニックなので・・・。ただ、JSONが限られたデータ表現しかできないというのは、悪意のあるコードを仕込むことが難しいという利点にもなります。JSONのパースに `eval()` を使わずに `JSON.parse()` を使うように、JSONPも厳密にパースされるようになるかもしれません。ところで `"hoge"` も正しいJSONです。

Comment: 「"hoge" も正しいJSON」。JSONについて根本的な点を勘違いしていたことに気が付きました。参考になりましたー

Comment: RFC6901 で厳密に規定されているJSONの仕様では *> JSON Pointer の評価は、 JSON 文書のルート値 【根元のオブジェクト／配列】 への参照から開始され，文書内の何らかの値への参照で完結する。 JSON Pointer の中のそれぞれの参照トークンは，記された順に評価される。
(Evaluation of a JSON Pointer begins with a reference to the root value of a JSON document and completes with a reference to some value within the document. Each reference token in the JSON Pointer is evaluated sequentially. ) [RFC 6901 - JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Pointer （日本語訳）](http://www.hcn.zaq.ne.jp/___/WEB/RFC6901-ja.html)* とあるように `"hoge"` はJavaScript Objectとしては正しいですが JSON としては正しいとは言えません。(**JSONの構成要素として**なら **正しい** です。)

Comment: @hinaloe まずそのRFCはJSONではなくJSON Pointerについてのものです。【】内は訳注であり、原文では示されていません。そしてJSONについて書かれた現在のRFCではobject/array以外も許容しています。 http://wiki.suikawiki.org/n/RFC%207159$984#anchor-47

Comment: @unarist そうですね、失礼しました。いくつかのJSON linter系サービスでもエラーがでていたため早とちりしてしまいました。確かに許容されてますね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

hoge.php 内の$argが文字列として扱われていないため、それぞれ展開後のjavascriptのコードが下記になります。

```
// check(9)
callback(9);
// check('沖縄')
callback(沖縄) // もちろん沖縄という変数が定義されていないのでエラー
```

なので、php側のprintを下記の様に修正することで解決します。

```
$arg = ($_GET['arg']);
print "callback(\"$arg\");";
```

また、実際引数にダブルクオートなどが含まれているとphp側でシンタックスエラーとなるので、`htmlspecialchars`などを使って対策して下さい。

Comment: 何の引数にダブルクオートが含まれているとphp側でシンタックスエラーになるでしょうか？

Comment: `check('"hoge')`のようにjs側からのコールに上記のエスケープの場合、phpでシンタックスエラーになります。

Comment: 文字列に埋め込んでいるからですか？埋め込まれた変数の展開というか、プログラムの実行は構文解析の後に行われる（感じだと思う）ので、エラーにはならないかと。 https://ideone.com/hyAoPZ （この場合JS側でエラーになりますが）